# Error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to char

Tags: java, stack

I've implemented a method to reverse a String using stack as ArrayList, but an error says `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to char`. How can I fix it?

Here is the stack class:

```
public static class stackl extends ArrayList {
    public boolean isEmptyS() {
        return isEmpty();
    }

    public void push(Object el) {
        add(0, el);
    }

    public Object pop() {
        return remove(0);
    }
}
```

And here is my method:

```
public static void reverse(String s) {
    stackl s1 = new stackl();
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(j);
        s1.push(ch);
    }

    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        char ch = s1.pop();
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read something about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a `char` to a `Character` with auto-boxing.  Try

```
Character ch = s.charAt(j);
```

Also, it would make sense to have a generic stack just like the built in `Stack` (have a look at the code for Stack as an example)